# File not in same subdirectory or sourcepath?

Tags: java, new-operator

I am new to Java and this is my essay to pass java. I found a template that I want to test, but the error is too strange for me to understand.

I must work in Netbeans ID 13 and the picture shows it all. But to me... I have the idea that I have everything on the same place. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8JXO.jpg)

I hope someone can help me to get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package and the directory names are both in lowercase. So 'com.mycompany.test1' not 'com.mycompany.Test1'. If the java source files are in the same package, then an import is not needed.

There might be something wrong within Options.java too. If so, please share the source code of it.